# Automate updating Wix database

Tags: velo

How can I automatically update wix database? The are only options to "Import/Export" CSV manually. For example, my computer program generates a CSV file every 6hr and how do I automatically update (replace entirely) the old database from the CSV file on my computer?

I use "to_csv" pandas function to save the dataframe as a CSV, so the generated CSV file will be in the same folder as my ipynb file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pull a file from a local drive on your computer/device.

You can use [HTTP Functions](https://www.wix.com/corvid/reference//wix-http-functions.html) to parse and send the .csv file from the external program to your site's API.

Then, use the [truncate()](https://www.wix.com/corvid/reference/wix-data.html#truncate) function to clear all data before inserting new data. I would suggest that you use the [bulkInsert()](https://www.wix.com/corvid/reference/wix-data.html#bulkInsert) function to insert your data.

However the HTTP Post request has to come from another program/cloud/server. Your Wix Site is not capable of pulling local files.

Comment: Google drive possible?

Comment: I'm not aware that Google Drive can make an HTTP Post call but if it can then yes it will be possible.